# Treating a file of Java floats as a lazy Clojure sequence

Tags: clojure, io

What would be an ideomatic way in Clojure to get a lazy sequence over a file containing float values serialized from Java? (I've toyed with a `with-open` approach based on line-reading examples but cannot seem to connect the dots to process the stream as floats.)

Thanks.

Comment: One float per line, or tab-separated, or space-separated?  Can you give some example data?

Comment: Clarification: The file consists of binary serializations of Java floats (i.e. the simple type "float"), it's not separated by anything. I want to do a calculation based on each entry in the (potentially very large) file - imagine I want to sum them all. I.e. I just want a lazy sequence over all the values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
(defn float-seqs [#^java.io.DataInputStream dis]
  (lazy-seq
    (try
      (cons (.readFloat dis) (float-seqs dis))
      (catch java.io.EOFException e
        (.close dis)))))

(with-open [dis (-> file java.io.FileInputStream. java.io.DataInputStream.)]
  (let [s (float-seqs dis)]
    (doseq [f s]
      (println f))))
```

You are not required to use with-open if you are sure you are going to consume the whole seq.

If you use with-open, double-check that you're not leaking the seq (or a derived seq) outside of its scope.

Comment: Great : it illuminated the use of lazy-seq in my mind. It finally clicked.